# Retrieving null value from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 jsp pages, the first jsp will display images with link to the second jsp page.

```
<a href='/display.jsp?src=<c:out value="${photo.source}"/>'>
```

In the display servlet, i have the following coding...

```
String srcLink = (String) req.getParameter("src");
    req.setAttribute("src", srcLink);
    getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/display.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Inside my second jsp (display.jsp), I have the following coding...

```
<img src="<%= request.getAttribute("src") %>" />
```

However, when I view in my browser, it will show as...

```
<img src="null" />
```

Is there any steps that I have done wrongly?

Comment: I think you can not pass values from one page to another page by clicking one a link as you are doing ahref.You should use a form for passing values

Comment: Why do you use an EL in one page (good) and a scriptlet in another one (bad)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to set the attribute as request.setAttribute(), as you are using the RequestDispatcher. It forwards the same request to other servlet/JSP. You just can use request.getParameter

use 
    **request.getParameter("src")**

instead

```
request.getAttribute(...)
```

so the code in **display servlet,** would look like:

```
    getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/display.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

and inside **display.jsp**,

```
<img src="<%= request.getParameter("src") %>" />
```

refer: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=206736

Comment: I have tried it and it is working. Thanks. `<img src="<c:out value = "${param.src}" />" />` is working too.

Comment: Yes,
<img src="<c:out value = "${param.src}" />"

also should work instead of req.getParameter(). Sorry I forgot to mention this. This is where you are using the JSTL. Using JSTL is always a better way. I don't prefer to use scriptlets in JSP, it should be avoided. However here I was trying to drive upon the concept rather than the code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess,You hit with syntax error.

```
<a href='/display.jsp?src=${photo.source}'>
```

Comment: Your href url is not correct since you have double quotes and a closing tag not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<a href='/display.jsp?src=${photo.source} />
```

in your first jsp page.

Comment: <a href='/display.jsp?src=${photo.source}'/>

Answer (score 0):

I have changed to the below and it is still not working...

```
<a href='/display.jsp?src=${photo.source}'>
```

Actually there is no error displayed on my first jsp page as I can see all the links being displayed correctly.

After much trying, I have removed the coding in my display servlet and changed the coding on my second jsp to...

```
<img src="<c:out value = "${param.src}" />" />
```

Now it is working fine. Thanks for the suggestion :)